# Is it wise to re-apply for visa again , If I think the officer hasnt considered all the necessary information?

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas, us-visa

So I am living and working in Europe for the past 4 5 years as an Engineer, I applied for US in 2020 and my visa application was accepted because I had strong ties to the country I am residing in. Now I got married last year and decided that we should plan a trip to visit her sister in the US , so she applied for a B2 visa.

In the interview they asked her that when did she move to this country(which was around 10 months ago), do you have a job ? (she used to work but now she doesn't) , and why is she visiting which she told her that she wants to visit her sister, but her visa was rejected with 214(b).

Now I can understand how the visa officer might have made a connection that she's unemployed, maybe looked for a job here and now she wants to move, but I think her strongest tie to this country is me(she moved here because of me). Although I wrote down in DS160 that I will be accompanying here but there was no place to enter my ties to the country or that I already have a visa. so would it be wise to apply again and to the question she adds this information too? or should we apply with a I-134 form of support that she is a genuine visitor and would return after spending a few days with her sister.

Answer (score 3):

Form I-134 would not be appropriate. It is filed for those asking to be paroled into the US, or potentially for visitors extending their stay. It is not filed to support a visa application.

It appears that the officer is considering the facts and circumstances of your spouse as risky. She is unemployed, recently moved to a new country (i.e.: can easily move again), recently married (i.e.: may have potentially gotten an immigration benefit due to the marriage and got disappointed and is now looking elsewhere), and has strong family ties in the US (i.e.: can easily find support and shelter once in the country). It is understandable why her visa application was denied.

I don't think there's any point reapplying if there's no change in circumstances.

Comment: Yeah -- it was a mistake to apply in the first place with ties this weak.